# Redis - Get the aggregated score from three sorted set

Tags: redis

i have three sorted sets:

`setA {play1: 100, play2: 150, play3: 230}
 setB {play1: 120, play4: 100, play5: 200}
 setC {play1: 110, play3: 150, play5: 30}`

Is it possible to get an aggregated result (sum the score for the same user in different sets and display all of users scores in the result) of the three sorted sets?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ZUNIONSTORE setSetSetAllMySets 3 setA setB setC AGGREGATE sum
```

`sum` happens to be the default aggregation and therefore isn't strictly necessary. I just wanted to get you interested in what other aggregations are available.

http://redis.io/commands/zunionstore